# ReferenceError: document is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am practising JavaScript from a course, and my code is exactly same as course tutorial, but it has a error and not working.

i have tried both ways:

```
const ul = document.querySelector('.players');
const ul = window.document.querySelector('.players');
```

but still have same problem.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1, shrink>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <title>ES6</title>
</head>


<body>

    <ul class="players"></ul>

</body>

<script src="nba.js"></script>

</html>

    const ul = document.querySelector('.players');


const players = [{
      jersey: 56,
      name: "Djounte Murray",
      position: "Point guard",
      PPG: 2.6
   },
   {
      jersey: 98,
      name: "Dennis Rodman",
      position: "Small Forward",
      PPG: 10.8
   },
   {
      jersey: 1,
      name: "Michael Jordan",
      position: "Small Forward",
      PPG: 345.6
   },
   {
      jersey: 2,
      name: "Lebron James",
      position: "Shooting Guard",
      PPG: 26.7
   },
   {
      jersey: 33,
      name: "Patrick Ewing",
      position: "Center",
      PPG: 20.2
   }
];

let list = '';
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
   let player = palyers[i];

   list += `<li>${player.jersey} - ${palyer.name} --- ${palyer.position} --- ${player.PPG}</li>`
}

ul.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", list);
```

error is :

```
const ul = document.querySelector('.players');
       ^
```

expected result is to print all the players information as the list, as below:

```
56,name:"Djounte Murray"- position:"Point guard"---PPG:2.6
98,name:"Dennis Rodman" - position:"Small Forward"---PPG:10.8
1,name:"Michael Jordan" - position:"Small Forward"---PPG:345.6
2,name:"Lebron James"- position:"Shooting Guard"---PPG:26.7
33,name:"Patrick Ewing"- position:"Center"---PPG:20.2
```

Comment: The javascript code needs to be inside the `script` tag.

Comment: Is this code inside `nba.js`?

Comment: @PrerakSola, yes it is in it <script src="nba.js"></script>

Comment: @brk, yes there are two files, one nba.html and one nba.js

Comment: The code looks good except some typing mistakes. You have `palyer` at few places instead of `player`

Comment: @PrerakSola yes, you are right, and now it is working perfectly, but in VS Code output still saying that part has a problem, but in chrome the result is correct.